# Cutting a rectangle into 3 congruent non-rectangular parts.

Tags: geometry

Can a rectangle be divided into n=3 congruent non-rectangular parts.Can the same be done for n=4?

Comment: For $n=4$ you can take a subdivision into four rectangles and put a "wiggle" in the two horizontal boundaries. (i.e. a bump downward followed by a bump upward.) Then the top tiles are rotations of the bottom tiles.

Comment: Just saw this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50085/can-a-rectangle-be-cut-into-5-equal-non-rectangular-pieces?rq=1

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Following that to [this answer on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11753/cutting-a-rectangle-into-an-odd-number-of-congruent-pieces/11766#11766), I came upon [Polyominoes of order 3 do not exist](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(92)90058-3). The way I read it, this does not cover the case of rotations by angles which are not multiples of 90°. For $n=4$ there are many examples, including [this one](http://math.cos.ucf.edu//~reid/Polyomino/t4_rect.html).